# Adding values to list elements based on condition (Python)

Tags: python

Say I got a list like this:

`list = [1, 2.1, 3.3, 4.5, 3.2, 4.7, 1, 3, 3.3, 3.9, 4.9]`

Now everytime the subsequent element in the list is less than the preceding element, i.e. `list[i] < list[i-1]` I want to add multiples of say 10 in ascending order to all the elements from this point until the next point where the condition is met. The resulting list for the example above should look like this:

`new_list = [1, 2.1, 3.3, 4.5, 13.2, 14.7, 21, 23, 23.3, 23.9, 24.9]`

So first 10 is added, then 20...
I'll mention that the length of each intervall is abritrarily long.

How could i achieve that elegantly? I did what I wanted by using the list as a temporary list and appending to a new list through a for and if loop but that seems rather ugly. I thought of doing it with list comprehension but I cannot figure out how this would work.

Comment: Please be aware that list is a builtin function in python to create lists. It is best to choose a different name for your variable. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: What should happen for a sequence like this: `[1, 4, 3, 12, 11]`?

Comment: oh, thanks for the remark.
@ekhumoro same thing

Comment: To be explicit: `3` is less than `4`, so after adding `10`, we get `[1, 4, 13, 12, 11]`. Now `12` and `11` are less than `13` - so do we add `10` to them as well? Or add `20`? If we add `10`, we get `[1, 4, 13, 22, 21]`. But now `21` is less than `22` - do we need to add `20` to that as well?

Comment: oh I'm sorry I did not look at your sequence carefully. So actually the list represents the times a certain event has been measured. But the timer only is of a certain length and then restarts. So in my example the threshold would be 10 before the timer restarts at 0. So the element 3.2 (after 4.5) would actually be 13.2 and so on. So the case you are mentioning would not occur.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `numpy` package. The idea is to first determine the positions where a the next value is lower. Then you do a cumulative sum and multiply this by 10. Finally you add this back to the original list.

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2.1, 3.3, 4.5, 3.2, 4.7, 1, 3, 3.3, 3.9, 4.9]
b = [0] + [int(a[i+1] < a[i]) for i in range(len(a)-1)]

aa = np.array(a)
ba = np.array(b).cumsum() * 10

print(aa + ba)

>>> [ 1.   2.1  3.3  4.5 13.2 14.7 21.  23.  23.3 23.9 24.9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1, 2.1, 3.3, 4.5, 3.2, 4.7, 1, 3, 3.3, 3.9, 4.9]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    while True:
        try:
            if list1[i] > list1[i+1]:
                list1[i+1] = list1[i+1] + 10
            else:
                break
        except:
            print("Done")
            break
        print(list1)

print("Final List: ")
print(list1)
```